# Error code E401 when trying to publish package using github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to use github actions to publish a npm package. This is the error I'm getting

[image]

This is the content of the publish.yml file:

```
name: Publish
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
        npm config set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken $TOKEN
        npm install
        npm run build
        npm publish
          env:
            TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: The alignment of your `run` section and its corresponding `env` isn't correct. Should be like [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdkD1vwyAQhnf/ihuy2h66MVWVoraqlGRw5wgoNdT4QL67LGn+e4jdRJVZEO/Hc+hQj07BQUwM5KuEqgLIQv52A5hJo/WOlhfUMOqA1U8ys2IkxK/FmgSpLm0QI8hSR82OeLaIXb4DCkGo4EBbDgmpLXA7JOHn09Mj4fB0j99Ot//Y7hRszmcgZyfH1Ly+d2+fL8fZgcvlES6/UPD7r4t5BJvwO/Sly9C2RWjy0Dd9YC+msWls1VEL+y4NDmEzI1eAgMQ6xpVaZi0LWOn5b5VX+fph1g==).

Comment: `env` could be placed before or after `run` but its indentation should be correct. [Here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdkLFuwyAQhnc/xQ1ZbQ/dmKpKUVtVSjK4cwSUGmp8IN9dljTvHmInVWUWdN9/fAegHp2Cg5gYyFcJVQWQhfxtBzCTRusdLRXUMOqA1U8yMzES4tcSTYJUl9MgRpCljpod8RwRu/wQFINQ0YG2HBJSW+R2SMLPp6e/juJS8HsvbwvzCDbhd+iBHEPbFtDkoW/6wF5MY9PYqqMW9l0aHMKm239sdytBQGId44qWWcszVjzfP+TBHJ7Uv5Z5gILN+VxuZCfH1Ly+d2+fL8c5gculugKxS2HW) is `env` after `run`.